# Problem sending information using POST method in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi i'm knew in django rest framework:

*views.py:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Book
from .serializers import BookModelSerializers


# for posting data 
class PostModelData(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = BookModelSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

*models.py:*

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default='', upload_to='store_image/', null=True, blank=True)
    fav = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

*urls.py:*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import GetAllData, Getfavdata, UpdateFavData, PostModelData

urlpatterns = [
    path('getalldata/', GetAllData.as_view()),
    path('getfavdata/', Getfavdata.as_view()),
    path('updatefavdata/<int:pk>/', UpdateFavData.as_view()),
    path('postmodeldata/', PostModelData.as_view()),
]
```

*serializers.py:*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Book


class BookModelSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I post `('name','store_name','description','fav')` with postman, the data that is stored is without details.

I wanted to know what the problem is?

I also removed `(blank = True)` in models.py, nothing is saved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWdM.png)

Comment: Can you add an example of the data you're sending with Postman

Comment: if i remove (Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)) from views.py, I get a 500 error

Comment: Change it so you get 500 Error, then send a request in Postman. When you get the response, click on 'preview' and you'll see it as rendered HTML. Then you can see the traceback of the error.

Post the error here or you'll figure it out yourself

Comment: it shows me this (AssertionError at /api/v1/postmodeldata/           
Expected a Response, HttpResponse or HttpStreamingResponse to be returned from the view, but received a <class'NoneType>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I looked at the picture your attached and found what's wrong.
You're sending your data as GET parameters in the URL. E.g. https://localhost:8000?name=lorem&storename=lorem2.

However, you have defined your view method to expect a POST request:

```
class PostModelData(APIView):
    #Use this method for POST requests
    def post(self, request):
        pass

    #Use this method for GET requests
    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

In this case though, when you want to receive data from the user and save it POST request is the correct choice, you just put your data in the wrong place.

Instead do this:

1: Change your code in your view

```
class PostModelData(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        #If you want to send MULTIPLE entries per request
        serializer = BookModelSerializers(data=request.data, many=True)
        #If you want to send ONE entry per request
        serializer = BookModelSerializers(data=request.data, many=False)
```

2: Go to Postman and do the following steps.

3: Remove all parameters from url so you just have http://localhost:8000/api/v1/postmodeldata/

4: Right next to the URL, make sure you have POST selected.

5: Under the URL bar, click on `Body`.

6: In the radiobuttons change to `raw`. And in the dropdown menu right next to it select `JSON`.

7: In the textarea write something like in this picture:

[Example request](https://gyazo.com/da042c29520793447aac51116873ade3)

8: Click Send and you should get a 201 response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BookModelSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        book = Book.objects.create(**validated_data)
        book.save()
        return book
```